# date1 before (1/month(date1)+2/month(year1)) vba access

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

i have a table collection(id,value,date)
how to use dsum to get the sum(value) where date is before last day of month(date1)+1

i tried

```
SomDom("[value]";"[collection]";"[date]<= format(dateserial(year([date1]);month([date1])+1;1)-1,'dd/mm/yyyy')")
```

but with no success, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that `DateSerial(Year, Month, 0)` returns the last day of the previous month, e.g.:

```
DSum("[value]","[collection]","[date] <= DateSerial(Year([date1]),Month([date1])+2,0)")
```

Comment: That's the last day of the month. Shouldn't it be: `DateSerial(Year([date1]);Month([date1])+2;0)`?